# Cannot import timezone from datetime module on Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not able to import `timezone` from the datetime module, but `timedelta` works just fine. I receive the error `ImportError: cannot import name timezone` and here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
JST = timezone(timedelta(hours=+9))
dt = datetime(2015, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=JST)
print(dt)

print(dt.tzname())

dt = datetime(2015, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=9), 'JST'))
print(dt.tzname)
```

Comment: the code snippet works for me with no issue

Comment: I have this same issue but given certain limitations I'm unable and not allowed to use the pyzt module and it's frustrating that there's no alternate solution other than someone saying don't use the timezone package, use pyzt. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for `import pytz` ([the timezone library](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/))

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
JST = pytz.timezone('Japan')
dt = datetime(2015, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=JST)
print(dt)
```

See timezone list here: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Working just fine now. I'll be looking more into this library. Thank you.